# equal widths for boxes in graphviz

Tags: graphviz, dot

Is it possible to get two boxes to be as wide as the widest one.

```
digraph G {
        node[shape=box];
        "A long description of a node" -> "short description";
}
```

Will produce:

[image]

But I want the two boxes' size to be aligned.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can control the (minimum) size of the box with the `width` and `height` parameters:

```
digraph G {
        node[shape=box, width = 2.5, height = .75 ];
        "A long description of a node" -> "short description";
}
```

yields

[image]

Comment: I was hoping there would be an automatic way but that's good enough for my case.